# Does Delphi 2010 have a LoadTextFromFile function?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

While porting some code from Delphi 7 to Delphi 2010 I was rewriting my LoadTextFromFile() function.

```
function LoadTextFromFile(const aFullFileName: string): string;
var
  lBuffer:     TBytes;
  lEncoding:   TEncoding;
  lFileStream: TFileStream;
  lSize:       Integer;

begin

  if not FileExists(aFullFileName) then
  begin
    raise Exception.Create('File "' + aFullFileName + '" not found.');
  end;

  lFileStream := TFileStream.Create(aFullFileName, fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyNone);
  try

    if lFileStream.Size <= 0 then
    begin
      Result := '';
    end
    else
    begin

      lSize := lFileStream.Size - lFileStream.Position;

      SetLength(lBuffer, lSize);

      // Read file into TBytes buffer
      lFileStream.Read(lBuffer[0], lSize);

      // Read encoding from buffer
      TEncoding.GetBufferEncoding(lBuffer, lEncoding);

      // Get string from buffer
      Result := lEncoding.GetString(lBuffer);

    end;

  finally
    lFileStream.Free;
  end;

end;
```

When a thought was hitting my head: there must be something like this in the standard library. Many users want to read a text file into a string, but I could not find such a standard function. The closest I came was using TStringlist to load text. But A) creating a TStringlist looks unnecessary and B) I don't want to suffer the overhead from TStringlist.

Question: is there a standard LoadTextFromFile function in Delphi 2010?

Comment: Even in Delphi 7, you didn't have to do all that. Use a `TStringStream` instead of a `TFileStream`, and use Marco's answer. Also, I'm curious: Under what circumstances have you ever found that the `Position` property wasn't zero immediately after creating a stream, such that you would need to subtract it from `Size` in order to calculate `lSize`?

Comment: Hi Rob, In Delphi 7 I had to be able to load/save to UTF8 files. And more importantly I did not know about TStringStream. The position does not need to be there. It is there because I copied some code out of the TStrings.Loadfromstream method that has the position in it. There is also another bug in my code as it does not handle files with BOM. So anyone thinking about using my example: don't. Use TFile.ReadAllText instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes exist one function like that in Delphi 2010, is called [`ReadAllText`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/IOUtils.TFile.ReadAllText) and is part of the `TFile` record declarated in the `IOUtils` unit.

Check this declaration

```
class function ReadAllText(const Path: string): string; overload; inline; static;
class function ReadAllText(const Path: string; const Encoding: TEncoding): string; overload; inline; static;
```

see this sample

```
program Project80;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  IOUtils,
  SysUtils;
Var
 Content : string;
begin
  try
    Content:=TFile.ReadAllText('C:\Downloads\test.css'); //load the text of the file in a single line of code
    //Content:=TFile.ReadAllText('C:\Downloads\test.css',TEncoding.UTF8); //you can an encoding too.
    Writeln(Content);
    Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for. Out of curiosity: when where IOUtils and TFile added to Delphi?

Comment: I did notice that TFile.ReadAllText puts an exclusive lock on the file when reading it. I would have preferred a fmShareDenyWrite lock.

Answer (score 4):

TStringStream.LoadFromStream/file ? Anyway very large strings are always a bit wasteful. You have to be very careful to not accidentally copy it.

Answer (score 2):

I tried the same solution, but made `lEncoding` a class variable to make it persistent, so I'd save my file to the same encoding as I read it.  However, the call to `GetBufferEncoding` does nothing if `lEncoding` is already set to something (as it would be if a previous file was read).  So, first I tried freeing it and that caused access violations all over the place.  Now I just set it to nil before making the second call and it seems to work.

Something like this:

```
if Assigned(lEncoding) then begin
  lEncoding := nil;
end;
GetBufferedEncoding(buffer, lEncoding);
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is TStringList.LoadFromFile().  Then use TStringlist.Text to access the data as one big string. Don't forget to create/free, ideally using a try..finally block.

Comment: This method requires many times the size of the file, and I wouldn't recommend it for large files.